# Logre que una JProgressBar se animara con un Timer, pero continua tirando excepciones

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, progressbar, timer

Llevo semanas con este problema, ya no sé cómo explicarlo o cómo encontrar la solución.

Mi idea original era crear un Timer que haga crecer la barra de progreso y otro que haga que la barra de progreso disminuya, ambos gradualmente.

Hice que el código funcionara, pero ahora, cada vez que se ejecuta, me produce una excepción, que no detiene el programa, pero molesta en realizar otras pruebas. Les dejo los dos fragmentos de código y las dos excepciones con la esperanza de que alguien pueda ayudarme.

```
        int obj = V;

        ActionListener al;
        Timer t;

        t = new Timer(25, new ActionListener() {
            int x;
            int obj;
            Timer t;

            {
                this.obj = V;
                this.x = HP.getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                HP.setValue(x);
                if ((x - obj) > 10) {
                    x = x - 3;
                } else if (between(x - obj, 6, 10)) {
                    x = x - 2;
                } else if (between(x - obj, 1, 5)) {
                    x = x - 1;
                } else {
                    t.stop();
                }
            }

        });
        t.start();
    }
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Juego$1.actionPerformed(Juego.java:618)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

El código de aumento:

```
public void aniEXP(JProgressBar PB, int V) {
        Timer t;

        t = new Timer(125, new ActionListener() {
            int x;
            int y;
            Timer t;

            {
                x = PB.getValue();
                y = V;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                PB.setValue(x);
                if (y > 20) {
                    x = x + 3;
                    y = y - 3;
                } else if (between(y, 11, 20)) {
                    x = x + 2;
                    y = y - 2;
                } else if (between(y, 1, 10)) {
                    x = x + 1;
                    y = y - 1;
                } else {
                    t.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

También aclaro todo lo que ya intente:

1. Hacer a Timer un atributo de la clase donde se ejecuta (Causa que la animación entre en un bucle y vuelva a iniciar repetidamente. Osea suponiendo que la ProgressBar tenga que aumentar, cambia de valores en forma de 0>1>0>1>2>0>1>2>3)
2. Definir el Timer en una clase aparte, el resultado es el mismo que el anterior.
3. Construir el Timer pasandole como atributo un objeto cuya clase implemente  Action listener. Directamente no funciono.

Comment: No se entiende nada

Comment: Hola @IJCS, estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, donde el idioma de las preguntas debe ser español. Traduce tu pregunta para que pueda ser reabierta, y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre la esta versión de la red StackOverflow (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno tras otra semana logre solucionarlo. El problema ahora aparece simple, pero guarda ciertos detalles curiosos. Lo dejo aquí por si otra persona con el mismo problema no sabe como solucionarlo.

Primero es imperativo definir al Timer como final, así poder llamarlo desde la clase ActionListener que se va a definir.

Luego hay que definir el Timer, que puede ser creado con un objeto null.

Por ultimo definir el ActionListener y agregarlo al Timer utilizando el Metodo addActionListener.

Y bueno...eso. Ahí les dejo el código corregido y final.

```
public void aniLHP(JProgressBar HP, int V) {
            int obj = V;

            ActionListener al;
            final Timer t;

            t = new Timer(25, null);

            al = new ActionListener() {
                int x;
                int obj;

                {
                    this.obj = V;
                    this.x = HP.getValue();
                }

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    HP.setValue(x);
                    if ((x - obj) > 10) {
                        x = x - 3;
                    } else if (between(x - obj, 6, 10)) {
                        x = x - 2;
                    } else if (between(x - obj, 1, 5)) {
                        x = x - 1;
                    } else {
                        t.stop();
                    }
                }

            };

            t.addActionListener(al);

            t.start();
    }
```